# why trigger click is making multiple requests under ready call

Tags: jquery

I am filtering the information based on alphabet Selection.

So initially on Page launch , i want to show information starting with letter **'a'**

But initially under **document ready**  code is making multiple requests ( all alphabets )

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.letter').trigger('click');
});

$(document).on("click", ".letter", function(event) {
  var alphabetname = $(this).data('alphabetname');
  if (!alphabetname || alphabetname == '') {
    alphabetname = 'a'
  }
  console.log(alphabetname);
  // Makes a ajax request here with the selected alphabet
});
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QZ3ff/2344/

Could you please tell me how to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('.letter[data-alphabetname="a"]').trigger('click');
});
$(document).on("click", ".letter", function(event)
{
        var alphabetname = $(this).data('alphabetname');
        if (!alphabetname || alphabetname == '')
        {
                alphabetname = 'a'
        }
        console.log(alphabetname);
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#container .element { width: 40px; height: 80px; margin: 3px; border: 1px solid black; }
.a { background-color: red;   }
.b { background-color: green; }
.c { background-color: blue;  }

/* Ensures specificity is higher that #container .element */
#container .element.width2  { width:  86px; }
#container .element.height2 { height: 166px; }

.portfolio_projects_hide {
    display: none;
}
/**** Isotope Filtering ****/
 .isotope-item {
    z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
 .isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    -ms-transition-property: height, width;
    -o-transition-property: height, width;
    transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
 .isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0s;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="alphabet">
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="a">A</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="b">B</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="c">C</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="d">D</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="e">E</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="f">F</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="g">G</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="h">H</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="i">I</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="j">J</li>
                                <li class="letter" data-alphabetname="k">K</li>
                            </ul>
```

Try this: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/QZ3ff/2345/)

```
$('.letter[data-alphabetname="a"]').trigger('click');
```